# how-to persist JSON into Grails domain objects with nested members

Tags: json, grails

Given these domain classes:

```
class Person {
    Long id
    String name

    static hasMany = [aliases: PersonAlias]
}

class PersonAlias {
    Person person
    Long id
    String name
}
```

I try to do a straight-forward round trip load/save through JSON land:

```
Person p = Person.get(20005353);
def json = p as JSON
def str = json as String
def map = JSON.parse(str)
p.properties = map
p.save(flush:true)
```

which produces this JSON

```
{
  "id": 20005353,
  "name": "John Smith",
  "class": "Person",
  "aliases":
  [
    {
      "class": "PersonAlias",
      "id": 99,
      "name": "J. Smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

And fails with this error:

> grails.validation.ValidationErrors: 1 errors Field error in object
>   'heavymeta.Person' on field 'aliases': rejected value [[]]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.heavymeta.Person.aliases,typeMismatch.aliases,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [heavymeta.Person.aliases,aliases]; arguments []; default
>   message [aliases]]; default message [Failed to convert property value
>   of type 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONArray' to required
>   type 'java.util.Set' for property 'aliases'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [heavymeta.PersonAlias] for
>   property 'aliases[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found]

Why does this fail, and is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a little suggestion (=. Check `params` in debug mode in `update` action(if you haven't generated views and controller for domain class run in console `generate-all Person`). Take a look to `params.aliases` you'll find it as list of ids. Try the same.